# Redis latency by fork

Tags: redis, latency

I read below paragraph from this link: http://redis.io/topics/latency

> For instance on a Linux/AMD64 system, the memory is divided in 4 kB
>   pages. To convert virtual addresses to physical addresses, each
>   process stores a page table (actually represented as a tree)
>   containing at least a pointer per page of the address space of the
>   process. So a large 24 GB Redis instance requires a page table of 24
>   GB / 4 kB * 8 = 48 MB.
>
> When a background save is performed, this instance will have to be
>   forked, which will involve allocating and copying 48 MB of memory. It
>   takes time and CPU, especially on virtual machines where allocation
>   and initialization of a large memory chunk can be expensive.

Pls help me explain:
1. Why do we multiple by 8 when calculate the memory for page table.
2. As I know, when Redis is persitent, it will save all dataset in it's memory to disk. Why in this document said, it's only save page table to disk.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why do we multiple by 8 when calculate the memory for page table.

Just as the document said, a page table contains at least a pointer. On a Linux/AMD64 system, a pointer takes 8 bytes. So you need multiple by 8 to get the size of the page table.

> 2. As I know, when Redis is persitent, it will save all dataset in it's memory to disk. Why in this document said, it's only save page table to disk.

The document DOES NOT say that it only saves page table. Instead, it tells you that when doing a background saving, Redis must do a fork, and the fork operation has to copy the page table.

Redis DOES save all data to disk. It DOES NOT save the page table to disk.